unique constraint with deleted_at IS NULL condition
How do I create a table with a WHEN SQL tag?
I want a table like this
"members_table",   {     id: serial("id").primaryKey(),     email: text("email").notNull(),     team_id: text("team_id").notNull(),     deleted_at: timestamp("deleted_at"),   },

Where I want unique to be like this
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX email_team_id_unique_idx ON members_table (email, team_id) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;

But in drizzle. Is that possible?
I want it to be that I cannot have the same mail and team_id twice. So test@test.com cannot be in team_id A and B, but can have test@test.com be in A and have deleted_at with NULL data, and have a test@test.com be in A and have deleted_at with Aug 15th 2024 at the same time. If that makes sense.
I'm using Next.js, Neon, PostgreSQL.

See https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/indexes-constraints#indexes, something like index(...).where(sql`deleted_at is null`).

@Dogbert the problem is that i need it to be unique, and uniqueIndex doesn´t have the .where command :/

Are you sure about that? Both index and uniqueIndex seem to return the same type: https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/blob/6adbd78748c8ecb687caa87b7cd775d86cdc0a2b/drizzle-orm/src/pg-core/indexes.ts#L245-L251.

@Dogbert this is the code that gets generated by Drizzle. And does not stop the push into the DB when email and team_id is the same.
SQL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "members_table" (  "id" serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,  "email" text NOT NULL,  "team_id" text NOT NULL,  "deleted_at" timestamp ); --> statement-breakpoint CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "unique" ON "members_table" USING btree ("email","team_id") WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;

Omg. I feel stupid now. I think my error was that each time i tried unigueIndex i imported for the wrong language! Now i saw that i needed to change to import from pg-core and it worked. My bad :/

I think my error was that each time I tried unigueIndex, I imported for the wrong language! Now I saw that I needed to change to import to pg-core and it worked.
